# Is it possible to download a file that uploaded via filepicker in chucks?

Tags: filepicker.io

Is it possible to download a file that I uploaded via filepicker, in chucks? I work on a platform that doesn't allow me to download files overs a certain size programmatically, (httprequest) so I have a need to retrieve the file in chucks and reassemble them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No we don't currently provide this functionality.